# Hibernate to initialize object in a different transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-transactions

I got the famous LazyInitializationException.

I have an object User which is stored in the session. This object contains an other object Market which is lazy initialized.
When I load the user in the session, I don't load Market because it is too heavy and I don't need it everytime.

When I want to load the market, I am in a different transaction and I don't want to reload the user from the database. How can I retrieve the Market object? Knowing that User.market contains the Hibernate proxy and so the id of the market and that I don't want to hack Hibernate using reflection.

That would be even better if I could load the market without loading it into the user. Since the user is in the session, I don't want to put a lot of stuff in the session.

A JPA compatible solution would be even better.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is to annotate the accessors instead of the fields. This will allow you to avoid loading of the market object when you initially load the user, but you will have access to the id of the market from the Hibernate proxy object without triggering a lazy loading or getting a LazyInitializationException. Then later on when you want to load the market itself you do a normal entity retrieval based on its id. You can read a detailed explanation of how this works [here](http://www.catalysts.cc/wissenswertes/ejb-annotations-hibernate-lazy-loading/?lang=en).

Answer (score 2):

If the eager mode fetching is not acceptable, and if the transaction cannot be maintained up to the Market retrieval, a specific dao method could be implemented to retrieve specifically the market from a user

```
public List<Market> retrieveMarketFromUser (final User user) {
  Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT m FROM User AS u INNER JOIN u.market as m WHERE u.userid = :uid");
  query.setParameter("uid", user.getId());
  List<Market> list = query.list();
  return list;
}
```

or the short version

```
  Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT u.market FROM User AS u WHERE u.userid = :uid");
```

This is maybe not the JPA solution you were expecting, just a workaround.

Comment: I have indeed thinked about that and that is the only JPA compatible solution that I have found so far. But the problem I got with this solution is the same which avoid me to reload the user : I don't want to do a query that involve the User table since this table is huge, while market has only 4 rows... Thanks anyway and even if it doesn't solve my problem, +1

Answer (score 1):

If the relation is bidirectional then you can load the Market independently using a query with clause like `where market.user.id = ?`.

Comment: See my comment on ring0 answer. That's indeed a solution but that doesn't satisfy me :(

Answer (score 1):

Why is the obvious solution not good? Like the one [ring0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338904/ring0) suggested, or simply using the `findById` or `find` methods if you already have the id in the `User` object.

```
//if using a session factory
session.findById(Market.class, marketId); 

//if using the EntityManager
em.find(Market.class, marketId);
```

Depending on how the `current_session_context_class` configured (I have it in `hibernate.cfg.xml`) you might have a new session with each new transaction. If that is the case the you do not need to worry about putting too much stuff in there. You can find more info on contextual sessions [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session).

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I was talking about HTTP session! The User contains indeed the id of the market but in the hibernate proxy object. I guess I can retrieve the id by doing something like : 

`( ( HibernateProxy ) user.getMarket()).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getIdentifier()`
Even if that is not JPA compatible, so far that is my best solution.

Comment: That is right, you should be able to simply get the id with a similar syntax (provided you have the user object): user.getMarket().getId().

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned new transaction , then you would probably working with a new hibernate session belonging to  thread ,

Use this incase of direct interaction with hibernate session

```
   obj = session.merge(obj);
```

In case your using JPA2 Api

```
   obj=   entityManager.merge(obj);
```

Please rate the answer if it helps.
Cheers

Comment: In my question : "I don't want to reload the user from the database". As you wish I rate your answer...

Comment: It works for me, but I have question: Why does it need to return new object instance? Why can't the initial one be "activated" to be use with new session?